# How to setup Botium Box

Tags: testing, chatbot

As per the details available at below link: https://medium.com/@floriantreml/botium-in-a-nutshell-part-3-automating-chatbot-tests-6c4e9e85121e

"*Botium Box includes management of your chatbot capabilities, so you won’t have to write those botium.json files by hand. Instead the configuration is done within an easy 3-step-wizard*"

Can someone let me know how to download and setup Botium Box on local machine ? Is there any user guide/handbook available? Please suggest.

Thanks,
Ravi

Comment: The product in question (Botium Box) will be launched very very soon (mid of january). It will be installable on-premise, on Heroku, docker - all of the state-of-the-art methods will be supported. Best way is to check the Botium website (https://www.botium.at) again in 1-2 weeks.

Answer (score 1):

•Install docker desktop version .It'll be installed with docker compose

•Create your own new folder

•Open command prompt and navigate to the newly created folder

• Eg:cd mynewfolder

• Type the below command in command prompt

curl --output docker-compose-all.yml https://raw.githubusercontent.com/codeforequity-at/botium-box-basic-dist/master/docker-compose-all.yml

Result - all packages will be installed.It'll take some time wait till installation is complete

• restart the docker.for info see docker in windows in link below
docker compose installation
https://docs.docker.com/compose/install/

main windows insallation steps
https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/install/

•Now enter the below command in cmd
up the local server .Everytime run this the main botium folder through cmd

run this to up the url-> docker-compose -f docker-compose-all.yml up

note -of you face any issues just restart the docker and then try the above command again
• paste the below url in browser

• Botium box will open in your browser

• Open the browser and enter the URL:http://127.0.0.1:4000

• Login to Botium Box

Default username: "admin"

Default password: "nooneknows"

• The above step will install botium box community edition which is the fastest way to launch Botium Box and all required components